# How do I match elements in rows in two separate data frames, for differing values and counts?

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, matching

I have two data frames, for which I have replicated real data below. The first data frame looks like:

```
FirstDataFrame <- data.frame("GroupID"   = c(1902, 1905, 1905, 1905, 1906, 1906, 1914, 1914, 1932, 1932, 1964, 1964, 1964), 
                         "SubjectID" = c(24626, 13300, 14126, 2619, 914, 872, 13325, 12539, 12597, 13314, 13343, 1723, 13333),
                         "Age"       = c(17, 13, 16, 17, 5, 9, 8, 14, 10, 13, 7, 14, 16))
```

The second data frame looks like, with the values for each `Age` being counts:

```
SecondDataFrame <- data.frame("OtherID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                          "Age5" =c(0, 0, 0, 11, 12, 57),
                          "Age6"= c(0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 52),
                          "Age7" = c(0, 0, 0, 12, 9, 42),
                          "Age8" = c(0, 0, 0, 9, 11, 50),
                          "Age9" = c(0, 0, 0, 12, 7, 46),
                          "Age10" = c(0, 0, 0, 12, 11, 41),
                          "Age11" = c(19, 0, 0, 9, 8, 42),
                          "Age12" = c(14, 0, 0, 13, 12, 39),
                          "Age13" = c(54, 78, 83, 0, 3, 13),
                          "Age14" = c(69, 101, 145, 0, 0, 0),
                          "Age15" = c(59, 114, 128, 0, 0, 0),
                          "Age16" = c(77, 127, 107, 0, 0, 0),
                          "Age17" = c(61, 91, 82, 0, 0, 0))
```

Each of those `AgeX` columns in `SecondDataFrame` correspond to a specific single-year age, as shown in the column name.

My objective is, for each `GroupID` in `FirstDataFrame`:

1. Extract the age values (perhaps into a vector). Note that some ages within `GroupID` may be the same. For example, I may have two 14-year-olds.
2. In `SecondDataFrame`, locate the `ID` row that contains the highest frequency of matches to the ages in that `GroupID` **and** contains a count of at least 1 (or at least 2, in the case where I have doubled-up ages) in the `GroupID`. That is, locate the `OtherID` row (or perhaps vector, I have thought about having one vector for each `OtherID`) which has the highest frequency of column (vector index?) matches.
3. Within the `GroupID`, allocate the chosen `OtherID` to each `SubjectID` that meets that criteria.
4. Decrease the count in the associated `AgeX` column by 1 for each match to that `OtherID`.
5. Repeat within `GroupID` until all `SubjectID` have an age match from `SecondDataFrame`.
6. Cycle to the next `GroupID`.

As you can see in `FirstDataFrame`, I have `GroupID` subjects who cannot all be allocated to the same `OtherID` in the `SecondDataFrame`. I also have varying numbers of subjects within each `GroupID`.

To make things even more complicated, there is no cut-off for the `OtherID` age columns such that if all the `OtherID` with a non-zero `Age11` have **either** all non-zero counts between the columns `Age5` through `Age10` **or** `Age12` through `Age17`.

I have cleaned the data such that each `AgeX` count in `SecondDataFrame` contains **at minimum** the same number of subjects of that age in `FirstDataFrame`. The minimum and maximum age values in `FirstDataFrame` and `SecondDataFrame` have been set so that these match exactly.

How do I ensure the maximum number of matches and decrease the counts appropriately? I've found some questions/answers that relate to obtaining the maximum number of matches. But:

1. They are doing a simple test of one vector against another single vector, and/or
2. They aren't decreasing the counts in the matched vector, but simply testing if an element exists (or not), or how many values in one vector match the values in another vector.

I can use nested `for ()` loops, but I am stuck on how to do the frequency matching and the decrease to the counts. I was thinking I needed to start the match at the youngest age in the `GroupID` and work with increasing age within `GroupID`, and that is the point at which I get stuck.

Edit: The finalised `FirstDataFrame` would look like:

```
FirstDataFrame <- data.frame("GroupID"   = c(1902, 1905, 1905, 1905, 1906, 1906, 1914, 1914, 1932, 1932, 1964, 1964, 1964),
                         "SubjectID" = c(24626, 13300, 14126, 2619, 914, 872, 13325, 12539, 12597, 13314, 13343, 1723, 13333),
                         "Age"       = c(17, 13, 16, 17, 5, 9, 8, 14, 10, 13, 7, 14, 16), 
                         "OtherID"   = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3)
```

However, the `OtherID` will also be chosen probabilistically. For example, the three teenagers in `GroupID` 1905 also have a probability of being in `OtherID` 1 or 2.

Correspondingly, the matched age cells will be decreased by 1 for each match in `SecondDataFrame`. So, for `GroupID` 1905, `OtherID` will end up with the counts:
`Count13` = 82, `Count16` = 127, and `Count17` = 81, which represent a decrease of 1 from the original counts, because each child match decreases the matches available by 1.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you want from Objectives 2 onwards. It will be helpful to break the problems into smaller manageable sizes. Would it be useful to have an example? First, say for `GroupID` 1905, you have an `Age` vector of 13, 16, 17; then are you supposed to pick the row in `SecondDataFrame` that has highest values of `Age13`, `Age16`, `Age17`? Does that mean `OtherID` 2 gets chosen because `Age16` is 127?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. There will be a probability match, how to do this I'm not yet sure - it will depend on how the matching is done. The main problem is making sure that all the kids in the same `GroupID` are matched to the same school, where the ages require this. And then decreasing each matched `OtherID` by 1. And that a 0 for any of the ages in the `OtherID` counts overrides all other matches for that `GroupID` set of children.

Comment: I've also thought about selecting on the basis of the smallest count. That will mean I don't end up with a lot of match problems because I have a lot of 0s for one age. I'll need to test this with various lots of synthetically constructed data, to see what breaks the matching. But first I have to be able to do the matching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long and tough problem to solve and I'm not sure I have answered everything.

Here's my way of approaching this problem, first by splitting `FirstDataFrame` according to `GroupID` and you get a list:

```
split_df <- split(FirstDataFrame, FirstDataFrame$GroupID)
split_df
#$`1902`
#  GroupID SubjectID Age
#1    1902     24626  17
#
#$`1905`
#  GroupID SubjectID Age
#2    1905     13300  13
#3    1905     14126  16
#4    1905      2619  17
#
#$`1906`
#  GroupID SubjectID Age
#5    1906       914   5
#6    1906       872   9
#
#$`1914`
#  GroupID SubjectID Age
#7    1914     13325   8
#8    1914     12539  14
# ...
```

Now I'll focus on one case and then we use a for loop to loop through it. I choose 1905 which is second element of the list. First extract the age of that group, then I want to create a vector of frequencies (instead of ages). I don't know of better way, so here's the inelegant solution

```
i = 2
ages <- split_df[[i]]$Age
ages
#[1] 13 16 17

ind_ages <- ages - 4 # "Indexize" ages: Age 5 become 1, 6 become 2, ..., 17 become 13
ind_ages
#[1]  9 12 13

freq <- tabulate(ind_ages, nbins = 13)
freq
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

The frequency vector has length 13, at 9-, 12- and 13-th position are one rest of them zero... This is to match with the column 2 to 14 in `SecondDataFrame`.

Now you can derive a way to randomly assign an OtherID to these kids. One possibility is to use the multinomial likelihood: Chances of getting 3 balls from bin 9, 12, and 13 given a set of probabilities assigned to the bins.

For each row in `SecondDataFrame`, we can calculate the proportion of each age (and use them as probabilities):

```
props <- apply(SecondDataFrame[,2:14], 1, function (x) x/sum(x))
props
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
#Age5  0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1222222 0.14814815 0.14736842
#Age6  0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1333333 0.09876543 0.13684211
#Age7  0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1333333 0.11111111 0.11052632
#Age8  0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.13580247 0.13157895
#Age9  0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1333333 0.08641975 0.11842105
#Age10 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1333333 0.13580247 0.10789474
#Age11 0.05428571 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.09876543 0.11052632
#Age12 0.04000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1444444 0.14814815 0.10263158
#Age13 0.15142857 0.1529412 0.1522936 0.0000000 0.03703704 0.03421053
#Age14 0.19714286 0.1980392 0.2660550 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#Age15 0.16857143 0.2235294 0.2348624 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#Age16 0.21714286 0.2490196 0.1963303 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#Age17 0.17142857 0.1764706 0.1504587 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Again, using `apply()`, we can calculate the likelihood of the three children coming the row (Note in `props` it becomes column).

```
likelihood <- apply(props, 2, function (x) dmultinom(freq, size = sum(freq), prob = x))
likelihood
#[1] 0.03382111 0.04032567 0.02699215 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000

prob_OtherID <- likelihood / sum(likelihood)
prob_OtherID
#[1] 0.3344025 0.3987156 0.2668819 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Probability of the kids belonging to `OtherID` 1 is 33.4%, 2 is 39.9% ... This is simply the weighted average of likelihoods. This way of calculation only works if you have small numbers of kids. If you have say 100s of kids in one group, this code break due to numerical issues.

Now use `sample()` to choose one `OtherID` for the kids, update the list.

```
chosenID <- sample(SecondDataFrame$OtherID, size = 1, prob = prob_OtherID)
split_df[[i]]$OtherID <- chosenID
```

Finally, go to the corresponding row in `SecondDataFrame`, subtract the age frequencies by the age frequency of this group of kids:

```
SecondDataFrame[SecondDataFrame$OtherID == chosenID, 2:14] <- 
    SecondDataFrame[SecondDataFrame$OtherID == chosenID, 2:14] - freq
```

Now put them into a for loop and job is done! A few more notes: for loop break at `i = 4` in this example because no row in `SecondDataFrame` simultaneously has Age 8 and 14 kid. Second, this algorithm does not guarantee you to be able to assign them all with an `OtherID` because as the frequencies get reduced in `SecondDataFrame`, you're increasingly likely to run into problem like that of `i = 4`. Perhaps you would be lucky to fill them all up without errors, or perhaps the capacity is much larger than the number of subjects then you'll be fine. Otherwise you'll have to think of other ways to deal with this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if I could keep the second data frame as a data frame instead of creating (in my current case) 15 different vectors.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes under the "base" R dataframe. It might complain if it's a `tibble`